# Display dynamic pdf image from URL and a dynamic link to that image

Tags: pdf, adobe, dynamic-content

I wish to embed some kind of an object in a PDF document in way that each time a document is opened the image is different (like some kind of HTML page that serves different images).

I don't want the image to be preset , instead i wish to change the image remotely (the server will serve different image)

In that way i want to be able to send a PDF newsletter that basically changes every time it is opened.

The thing i need to change on each document open is the image and the link that the user will go to once clicking the image.

Is this possible ?